# Android - get location from network once

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm kinda stuck here.. Basically I am trying to get the user's zip code location. I have the code to get a ZIP from GPS coordinates, but I can't seem to get any coordinates. This is the code I have so far -

```
Log.d(TAG, "Zip is going to be autoset");
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        LocationManager locationManager;
        String provider;
        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            }
        };

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);//true if required
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);//true if required
        criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);//search for enabled provider
        //locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, locListener, null);
        Location location= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        Log.d(TAG,"Lat - " + (location.getLatitude()) + " long - " + (location.getLongitude()));
        latitude = (location.getLatitude());
        longitude = (location.getLongitude());
        Log.d(TAG, "Passing this link https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng="+latitude+","+longitude+"&sensor=true");
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locListener);
        try {
        //Log.d(TAG, "Trying to access "+ "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng="+location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude()+"&sensor=true"
            //Log.d(TAG, "Trying to access "+ "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true");
            URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng="+latitude+","+longitude+"&sensor=true");
            InputStream stream = url.openStream();
            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (true){
                int data = buf.read();
                if (data==-1){
                    break;
                }else{
                    sb.append((char)data);
                }
            }
            int zipEnd = sb.indexOf("</short_name><type>postal_code");
            Log.d(TAG,"ZIP is "+sb.substring(zipEnd-6, zipEnd));
            ZipCode = Integer.parseInt(sb.substring(zipEnd-6, zipEnd));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}.run();
```

The latest error I've been getting says that I cannot create a handler inside a thread that hasn't called looper.prepare.

All I need is one coarse location update (network location will be perfect) so I can get a zip code from it.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598910/android-getting-network-gps-location-within-a-short-time-frame-10-seconds-max)?

Comment: is the above code in an activity?

Comment: You are saying you are having problem with Handler but i am not seeing you used handler anywhere on the paste code. is that all of your code? and for zip code you can use Geocoder you dont have to use something else.

Comment: the code is part of an intentService which is supposed to get the zip then feed the zip to a website and download data for the user's location.

Comment: this is all the code relevent to the gps. there is more code, but it is for the second part of the program. if i comment this out and feed a zipcode directly to the second part it works perfectly so i think the problem is in the code above

Answer (score 1):

Look into using [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29)

Create a list of Addresses and then use [getPostalCode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getPostalCode%28%29)

Comment: thanks. i'll use this to refactor the zipcode code. do you have any suggestions to get the gps data?

Comment: If you were actually displaying a map I'd say use google maps of the Google Play Services. But since it's just coordinates I'd use [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `new Thread()`   change to new `Thread(new Runnable()`

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{   

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Looper.prepare();

        // The rest of your code in between 
        // LocationManager locationManager;
        // and 
        // catch (IOException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // }

        Looper.loop();
    }
}).start();
```